# How to make a Cage Fighting Simulation with user input instead of random for Python

Tags: python, simulation

Here is my code so far using `random` to pick moves:

```py
import time
import random

PHealth = 10
CHealth = 10

PShots = [
    "Great Body Shot To Your Opponent!", 
    "Nice Take Down!", 
    "Nice Punch!", 
    "Strong Kick!", 
    "You Have Him Pinned Against The Cage!", 
    "Excellent Counter-Shot!"
]
CShots = [
    "You Took a Shot to the Body!", 
    "You Got Taken Down!", 
    "Strong Kick Hit You!", 
    "You Took A Big Punch!", 
    "You Are Pinned Against The Cage", 
    "Counter-Shot Got Ya!"
]

for i in range(20):
    i = random.randint(0, 100)
    if i >= 51:
        print(random.choice(PShots))
        CHealth = CHealth -1
        if CHealth >= 1:
            print("Player Health", PHealth)
            print("Computer Health", CHealth)
            time.sleep(5)
    if i <= 50:
        print(random.choice(CShots))
        PHealth = PHealth -1
        if PHealth >= 1:
            print("Player Health", PHealth)
            print("Computer Health", CHealth)
            time.sleep(5)
    if CHealth < 1:
        print("What A Shot!")
        time.sleep(1)
        print("Down He Goes!")
        time.sleep(1)
        print("The Referee Has Stopped The Fight!!")
        time.sleep(1)
        print("Player Wins!!!")
        break
    if PHealth < 1:
        print("What A Shot!")
        time.sleep(1)
        print("Down You Go!")
        time.sleep(1)
        print("The Referee Has Stopped The Fight!!")
        time.sleep(1)
        print("Computer Wins!!!")
        break
```

Basically I'd like to understand how a player can input one move. So if a player inputs `body shot` it beats `take down`. If a player inputs `kick` it beats `punch`. If a player inputs `take down` it beats `pinned against the cage`, etc. Thinking 6-7 variations and counters.

Comment: It is not entirely clear, what game logic you want to achieve. Can a player (/computer) **react** to a move by the opponent or do both pick their moves a priori?  What does it mean for a move to "beat" another? That only the player with the "beaten" move takes damage or that he takes _more_ damage than the other? Does every pair of moves have a winning and a losing one or can there be "draw" situations? What should happen then?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an idea of how you could implement something akin to what you seem to be looking for using a mix of classes and functions.

The following code should work with Python `3.9+` and has no additional dependencies.

First we define a `Move` class, instances of which need to have a `name`, a `text_used` (for when the player successfully uses the move), and a `text_affected` (for when move is used against the player). Each instance also stores a set of other `Move` objects, which it trumps, as well as a set of those it is trumped by. We have a helper method `should_beat` to easily define such a relationship between two moves.

```py
class Move:
    def __init__(self, name: str, text_used: str, text_affected: str, damage: int = 1) -> None:
        self.name: str = name
        self.text_used: str = text_used
        self.text_affected: str = text_affected
        self.damage: int = damage

        self.trumps: set['Move'] = set()
        self.trumped_by: set['Move'] = set()

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.name

    def should_beat(self, other_move: 'Move') -> None:
        self.trumps.add(other_move)
        other_move.trumped_by.add(self)
```

Next we define a `Player` class. Its instances have a `name` and an optional `starting_health` set to a previously defined constant by default.

A `Player` also has a `use_move` method that takes a `Move` object, another `Player` object (the opponent), and a second `Move` object (the move used by the opponent). That method checks which move beats which and calculates the health subtraction accordingly.

Finally, the `Player` object has `win` and `lose` methods that can be called to print out the win/loss statements when necessary.

```py
class Player:
    def __init__(self, name: str, starting_health: int = DEFAULT_STARTING_HEALTH) -> None:
        self.name: str = name
        self.health: int = starting_health

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.name

    def use_move(self, move: Move, vs_player: 'Player', vs_move: Move) -> None:
        if vs_move in move.trumped_by:
            self.health -= vs_move.damage
            print(vs_move.text_affected)
        elif move in vs_move.trumped_by:
            vs_player.health -= move.damage
            print(move.text_used)
        else:
            print(TEXT_NO_EFFECT)

    def win(self, vs: 'Player') -> None:
        print("What A Shot!")
        sleep(1)
        print(f"{vs} Goes Down!")
        sleep(1)
        print("The Referee Has Stopped The Fight!!")
        sleep(1)
        print(f"{self} Wins!!!")

    def lose(self, vs: 'Player') -> None:
        print("What A Shot!")
        sleep(1)
        print(f"Down You Go, {self}!")
        sleep(1)
        print("The Referee Has Stopped The Fight!!")
        sleep(1)
        print(f"{vs} Wins!!!")
```

Next, we want a function to **define** our moves and one that conveniently prints a list of moves to the terminal. Obviously you will want to **expand the `define_moves` function** to incorporate all your desired moves and their relationships. It should return a list of **all** your `Move` objects.

```py
def define_moves() -> list[Move]:
    kick = Move("kick", "Strong Kick!", "Strong Kick Hit You!")
    punch = Move("punch", "Nice Punch!", "You Took A Big Punch!")
    ...
    kick.should_beat(punch)
    ...
    return [
        kick,
        punch,
    ]


def print_moves(moves_list: list[Move]) -> None:
    print("Available moves:")
    for i, move in enumerate(moves_list):
        print(i, "-", move.name)
```

Now for the fun part, we need our main fighting loop. In each iteration, we prompt the player for a number that corresponds to an index in our **list of moves** defined earlier. (The player may also type `h` to see the moves again.) We do some checks to make sure we received a valid number to get our `Move` object.

Then we randomly chose a move for the computer opponent out of our moves list, and call our `use_move` method. It does the health calculations for us. So after that we just check, if someone is done to call the appropriate `win` or `lose` method and break out of the loop. Otherwise we print the current health stats and continue.

```py
def fight_computer(player: Player, moves_list: list[Move]) -> None:
    computer = Player(name="Computer")
    while True:
        string = input('Choose your move! (or type "h" to see available moves again)\n').strip().lower()
        if string == 'h':
            print_moves(moves_list)
            continue
        try:
            i = int(string)
        except ValueError:
            print("You need to pick a number!")
            continue
        try:
            move = moves_list[i]
        except IndexError:
            print("No move available with number", i)
            continue

        computer_move = choice(moves_list)
        print(computer, "chose", computer_move)
        player.use_move(move, vs_player=computer, vs_move=computer_move)

        if player.health < 1:
            player.lose(vs=computer)
            break
        if computer.health < 1:
            player.win(vs=computer)
            break

        print(player, "health:", player.health)
        print(computer, "health:", computer.health)
        sleep(1)
```

Lastly, we need a `main` function to put it all together, prompt the player for his name, etc.

```py
def main() -> None:
    player_name = input("Enter your name: ").strip()
    player = Player(player_name)

    moves_list = define_moves()
    print_moves(moves_list)

    fight_computer(player, moves_list)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Don't forget to add your imports and constant definitions to the start of the module:

```py
from random import choice
from time import sleep


DEFAULT_STARTING_HEALTH = 10
TEXT_NO_EFFECT = "Your move had no effect!"
```

All together, this should give you a crude version of the game you described. Try it out. Hope this helps.